# Using \newcommand to create a math symbol

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have seen some examples of using `\newcommand` to create a new math symbol, e.g.,

> ```
> \newcommand\indep{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
> \def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2.5mu{#1#2}}}
> ```

but unfortunately this appears as obscure nonsense to me.

I would like to create a new math symbol, which is easily visualized: similar to `\oplus` but with a smaller (centered) circle, like the one given by `\circ`, so that the lines of the + stretch outside of the circle.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, `\stackinset`ing a `\circ` over a `+`.  Using `scalerel` to carry it across all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\stackMath
\newcommand\circplus{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{\dimexpr.1pt-.4\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\circ}{\SavedStyle+}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
1 + 2 \oplus 3 \circplus 4_{\circplus_{\circplus}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For something that fits the `\oplus` line widths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,graphicx}
\def\pieceA{\scalebox{.8}{$\scriptscriptstyle{-}\kern3pt{-}$}}% THE 3pt CAN VARY ARM LENGTH
\savestack\Xoplus{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\pieceA$}%
  \ensurestackMath{%
  \kern.5\wd0%
  \makebox[0pt]{%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}%
      {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\copy0}}%
      {\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\copy0}{\oplus}}%
  }%
  \kern.5\wd0
  }%
}
%\newcommand\xoplus{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\Xoplus}{\oplus}}}% FOR SIMPLE, AS IS SCALING
% FOR TUNABLE SCALING using \xoplusscale
\newcommand\xoplusscale{1}
\newcommand\xoplus{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  $\SavedStyle\scalerel*{\Xoplus}{\vstretch{\xoplusscale}{\oplus}}$}}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
1 + 2 \oplus 3 \xoplus 4_{\xoplus_{\xoplus}}
\]
\renewcommand\xoplusscale{1.5}
\vspace{-12pt}
\[
1 + 2 \oplus 3 \xoplus 4_{\xoplus_{\xoplus}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer looks visually the same as the one above. The problem is that I would like to recreate the thin lines of `\oplus`, but not the (relatively) bold lines of +.

Comment: @PseudoRandom I will give it some more thought.  Do you want an `\oplus` with the lines extended or an `\oplus` with the circle shrunk?

Comment: If you can do both, it would be awesome. Otherwise, an `\oplus` with the circle shrunk is good enough.

Comment: @PseudoRandom As you wish... though it is a more complicated calculation.

Comment: It is surprising how complicated a circle inside a + can be in LaTeX. In any case, the big one (scale=1.5), visually, looks better.

Comment: @PseudoRandom even for the simplest of glyphs, say a minus, `-`, one must consider issues of line thickness, vertical/horizontal placement, overall scale, and surrounding space.  All of these must be addressed any time you want to put a new symbol on the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Picture mode to the rescue!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\pseudorandom@cplus\relax}}
\newcommand{\pseudorandom@cplus}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1+$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \linethickness{.06\unitlength}%
    \begin{picture}(\wd\z@,1)
    \put(0.5\wd\z@,0.5){\circle{0.5}}
    \put(0,0){\raisebox{\depth}{\box\z@}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup % show the bounding boxes
\fboxsep=-0.1pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{$+$}\fbox{$\cplus$}

\nointerlineskip
\fbox{$\cplus$}\fbox{$+$}
\endgroup

% test for the spacing and subscripts

$a+b\cplus c_{+\cplus}$

$a\cplus b+c_{+\cplus}$

\medskip

% test for larger size

{\LARGE$a\cplus b+c_{+\cplus}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For lighter strokes to accompany `\oplus`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cplus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\pseudorandom@cplus\relax}}
\newcommand{\pseudorandom@cplus}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1+$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \linethickness{.06\unitlength}%
    \begin{picture}(\wd\z@,1)
    \put(0.5\wd\z@,0.5){\circle{0.5}}
    \put(0,0){\raisebox{\depth}{\box\z@}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=-0.1pt \fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{$+$}\fbox{$\cplus$}

\nointerlineskip
\fbox{$\cplus$}\fbox{$+$}

$a+b\cplus c_{+\cplus}$

$a\cplus b+c_{+\cplus}$

\medskip

{\LARGE$a\cplus b+c_{+\cplus}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why loading `picture` after `pict2e`? `pict2e` should already load `picture`, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @FranckPastor I don't think so.

Comment: My bad, I mistook the `picture` package with the `picture` environment…